# Winform TreeView with checkboxes - only visible nodes are updated

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, checkbox

I am new here, and have searched for answers for my problem practically everywhere - to no avail. I hope that somebody here can help.

I have a WinForm application, where I use a TreeView to display the folder structure below a selected root folder. The treeview has enabled CheckBoxes. When I check or uncheck a checkbox on a TreeNode, any visible nodes below that TreeNode changes as well - so far so good.

The problem is, that when I expand the nodes further, then the new visible nodes are *not* updated to the correct state.

I used the following recursive routine to perform the update:

```
    private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            node.Checked = nodeChecked;
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                // If the current node has child nodes, call the
                // CheckAllChildNodes method recursively.
                CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
            }
        }
    }
```

It is called from this event handler:

```
    private void FileTreeView_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // The code only executes if the user caused the checked state to change.
        if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByMouse)
        {
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                // Calls the CheckAllChildNodes method, passing in the current
                // checked value of the TreeNode whose checked state changed.
                CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems that the recursive function only cares about TreeNodes that are visible at the time of execution.

If anyone can give a clue of what is wrong, and what can be done to correct it, it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

L. Hummel

Answer (score 2):

Two things.  One, you don't need the "if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)" in either.  That is a little redundant as if there are 0 nodes when you call a "foreach", it immediately passes out of the loop.

Two, the easiest solution may be to just wire into the AfterExpand method, and when the node gets expanded, set the children then:

```
private void FileTreeView_AfterExpandobject sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    // Calls the CheckAllChildNodes method, passing in the current
    // checked value of the TreeNode whose checked state changed.
    CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);        
}
```

Also, are you sure you want TreeViewCancelEventArgs in your event methods, and not just TreeViewEventArgs?

Answer (score 1):

If you use data binding then it's likely not a TreeView problem, it is an issue with data binding. It doesn't update controls that aren't visible. See this [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/70f0bbbb-07d5-4253-9a79-789700a8450a) for Winforms Tabcontrol issue.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to replicate what you might be doing in the code can you please use this code and confirm is it working or you are facing the same problem.

```
 private void PopulateFolderTreeView(string directories, TreeNode parentNode)
            {
                string[] directoriesArray = Directory.GetDirectories(directories);
                string[] filesArrays = Directory.GetFiles(directories);
                if (directoriesArray.Length != 0)
                {
                    foreach (string currentDirectory in directoriesArray)
                    {
                        TreeNode myNode = new TreeNode(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentDirectory));
                        if (parentNode == null)
                        {
                            treeView1.Nodes.Add(myNode);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            parentNode.Nodes.Add(myNode);
                        }
                        PopulateFolderTreeView(currentDirectory, myNode);
                    }

                }
                if (filesArrays.Length != 0)
                {
                    foreach (string currentFile in filesArrays)
                    {
                        TreeNode myNode = new TreeNode(Path.GetFileName(currentFile));
                        if (parentNode == null)
                        {
                            treeView1.Nodes.Add(myNode);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            parentNode.Nodes.Add(myNode);
                        }
                        //PopulateTreeView(currentDirectory, myNode);
                    }

                }
            }



     private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
                {
                    node.Checked = nodeChecked;
                    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // If the current node has child nodes, call the
                        // CheckAllChildNodes method recursively.
                        CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
            {
                // The code only executes if the user caused the checked state to change.
                if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByMouse)
                {
                    if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // Calls the CheckAllChildNodes method, passing in the current
                        // checked value of the TreeNode whose checked state changed.
                        CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
                    }
                }

            }
```

put this line either in Form Load event or Button Click event

```
PopulateFolderTreeView(@"C:\Program Files\", null);
```

Comment: I don't think the OP has any problems populating the treeview in the first place.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried to implement the methods you described, but when I run the application and tries to execute the line



I get the following runtime-error:

"UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled"

"Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\' is denied."

I've checked the credentials, and they seem ok everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, the line I am talking about is the line "string[] directoriesArray = Directory.GetDirectories(directories);"

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986293/access-to-the-path-is-denied-when-using-directory-getfiles