# How to correctly search for files in C#

Tags: c#, exception, search, filter, getfiles

Currently I am using the following code to search for files in a folder:

```
public string[] getFiles(string SourceFolder, string Filter,System.IO.SearchOption searchOption)
{
    // ArrayList will hold all file names
    ArrayList alFiles = new ArrayList();

    // Create an array of filter string
    string[] MultipleFilters = Filter.Split('|');

    // for each filter find mathing file names
    foreach (string FileFilter in MultipleFilters)
    {
        // add found file names to array list
        alFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolder, FileFilter, searchOption));
    }

    // returns string array of relevant file names
    return (string[])alFiles.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

The problem is that when I pass a drive like `D:\\` as the path to search, either I get an exception in `GetFiles()` or nothing is found!

I also get exceptions when I try to access some hidden or system secured folder.

How can I properly search for files in a drive or folder recursively?

One more thing, I come to know that a extension like "abc" may return files with having extensions like "abcd" or "abcde".

If this is true, how can I overcome this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986293/access-to-the-path-is-denied-when-using-directory-getfiles

Comment: The easiest would be to wrap the GetFiles in a try/catch

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Got the solution, thanks everyone.
Here's my solution
http://pastebin.com/D2Ta9Ukb